# Importing SSIS packages to SQL 2014

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I am importing my SQL 2008 R2 packages into my SQL 2014 server. I'm noticing there are 2 ways to do this

1. Integration Services Catelog -->SSISDB
2. Connect to SSIS -->Stored Packages

I'm trying to understand the difference between the 2 ways. I like the SSISDB way better. Don't ask me why. I just do.

Is one way the "new" way or "proper" way and the other way is just for backwards compatibility?

Comment: That is covered in the documentation. The difference is important enough that you should check the docs instead of picking one or the other. It has nothing to do with database vs stored packages, it's about the Package-based or Project-based deployment model

Answer (score 0):

You can export the SSIS Project to Sql server data tools 2014 by opening the exported ispac file in Visual Stdio 2012 or newer version.

You just right click on the deployed project and export the ispac file to a particular location in your system.

Now, Open Visual Studio and open business integration import project and browse that file.

Here, your packages in that project will be upgraded to newer version of SSIS.

Hope, this could help you!